# Можно ли в скрипте при с помощью python эмулировать нажатие левой кнопки мыши по объекту?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Пишу парсер для сайта. Некоторый объект по нажатию на него вызывает событие. Можно ли как нибудь эмулировать нажатие в коде? Погуглил, нашел библиотеку mouse - https://github.com/boppreh/mouse. Потихоньку разбираюсь в функционале. Но я так и не понял, можно ли этим эмулировать нажатие на сайте при парсинге? Мб есть другие варианты у кого?

Comment: Да, есть squish

Comment: @Andrey, при парсинге сайта работает,?

Comment: Вроде есть там автоматизация тестирования сайтов

Comment: можно на selenium парсер написать

Answer (score 2):

> Попробуйте selenium, там можно запускать даже headless программы(без
>   запуска браузера как такового).

Небольшое уточнение. Selenium это прослойка между кодом на пайтоне и браузером, запускающим браузер в режиме удаленного управления и если браузер поддерживает headless режим, то его можно запустить в нем, так как селениум позволяет указать параметры запуска браузера. Селениум всегда будет запускать браузер, а headless режим лишь скрывает окно браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте selenium, там можно запускать даже headless программы(без запуска браузера как такового).

https://proglib.io/p/web-scraping

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/